# How to setup a battle?

Tags: civilization-5

I would like to play an already built empire against another one(s) of equal strenght, with prebuilt armies.

It could be something like a WWII scenario present in previous versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment Faraxis has not released any scenarios with Civilization 5.

It is possible to create your own maps and scenario's using the world builder and modding tools so I hope it wont be long before WWII and similar scenario's are created by the community though, which is just as good in my opinion.

**Edit: Faraxis released a Mongolian scenario in a free online patch**. I assume this indicates that there will be more to come in time.

Comment: Firaxis*********

Comment: It's sad yes, but I would rather have the game now as is, than have firaxis delay the release till 2011